# Converting MATLAB to Python: too many indices return error

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, indexing

I am attempting to convert a script I have in MATLAB to Python in order to increase speed and efficiency of the overall algorithm. In MATLAB, the code is as follows:

```
for iter = 1:T
costi = costo;
for i = 1:length(index)
    for j = i+1:length(index)
        if index(j) == index(i)
            continue;
        end
        indexdn = indexd;
        indadd = (index(j) - index(i));
        indexdn(:,j) = indexdn(:,j) + indadd;
        ##line 11
        indexdn(j,:) = -indexdn(:,j)';            
        indexdn(j,j) = 0;
        indi = abs(indexdn);
        indi = ~indi;
        costnb = costmata.*indi;
        costn = 0.5*(sum(sum(costnb)));
        if costn < costi
            costi = costn;
            index(j) = index(i);
            indexd = indexdn;
        end
    end
end
if costi < costo
    costo = costi;
else 
    break
end
iter
end
```

I have completed most of the translation:

```
for j in range(0,T):
cost2 = cost1
for x in xrange(len(index)):
    for y in xrange(x+1,len(index)):
        if index[y] == index[x]:
            continue
        indexdn = indexd
        indadd= index[y]-index[x]
        print indadd
        indexdn[:,y]=indexdn[:,y]+ indadd
        index[y,:]=-indexdn[:,y] ##line 11, return error
        indexdn[y,y]=0
        indi= np.abs(indexdn)
        indi= ~indi
        costnb = costmata*indi
        costn = .5(np.sum(costnb))
        if (costn < cost2):
            costi=costn;
            index[y] = index[x]
            indexd= indexdn
if cost2<cost1:
    cost1=cost2
else:
    break
```

however, on line 11, I am returned an error of "index error: too many indices." What is causing Python to get tripped up on this line? How can I write my Python code so that I am not returning this error? *index* array is a numpy array predefined with length 16 with random integers 0-5, *indexd* array is a 16x16 array with random integers -5 to 5, and *indexdn,indadd* are being created within this iteration.

Comment: Translating an iteration like this isn't going to improve speed.  Modern MATLAB 'compiles' loops like this.  Python/numpy like older MATLAB versions, requires 'vectorization' to achieve its speed.

Comment: I don't know if this affects your error but you have `indexdn(j,:) = -indexdn(:,j)'` (transpose) in your Matlab code but not in your python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `index` is a 1-d array? (you have `index[y]` and `index[x]` on line 5 and 8, and say it is of length 16)

But, on line 11, you are trying to access its second dimension: `index[y,:]`. Maybe that should be `indexdn[y,:] =-indexdn[:,y]`?